# Understanding reflexive, symmetric, and antisymmetric relation with an example

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let A be a finite, non-empty, non-singleton set. Let R(A) denote the set of all reflexive relations on A , S(A) denote the set of all symmetric relations on A and T(A) denote the set of all anti-symmetric relations on A. Then, are the following true?

1.|S(A)∩T(A)|=1

2.(S(A)∩T(A))⊂R(A)

1. For the first statement, I believe it is true as the intersection of symmetric and antisymmetric set will have only one element as the common element.
2. The symmetric and antisymmetric set will also have none of the elements as the common element, so the intersection will have no element. So, what it means by R(A) as superset of ((S(A)∩T(A)) is the first one includes the elements of the second one. R(A) will have other elements, that makes it superset of (S(A)∩T(A)).

Answer (score 0):

The first one is wrong: Since you want the relation to be both symmetric and anti-symmetric, you only can have elements of the form $(a, a)$. (if $(a, b)$ is an element with $a \neq b$ then $(b, a)$ will be as well according to symmetry and then $a = b$ according to anti-symmetry, which is a contradiction). Since $|A| = n$, we'll have $|S(A) \cap T(A)| = 2^{n}$. For the second one, according to what I just said, $S(A) \cap T(A)$ can only have elements of the form $(a, a)$ (but not all of them necessarily) so the second statement is false.

Comment: Despite being elementary for many, could you please explain how |S(A)∩T(A)|=2^n.

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions Any of the elements $(a, a)$ can be or not be in the relation so according to the multiplication principle the answer is $2^{n}$.

Comment: For the second one, is it what it means. There is an instance (S(A)∩T(A)) with element (a,a) and R(A) with element (b,b), thereby disqualifying (S(A)∩T(A))⊂R(A). This will qualify ((S(A)∩T(A))⊂R(A)) for the instance when all the elements (a,a), (b,b)... included on both sides (((S(A)∩T(A)), R(A))?

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions The second one's answer is there is a symmetric and anti-symmetric relation which doesn't contain all elements of the form $(a, a)$ so it's not reflexive so the second statement is false.

Comment: My apology for my limited understanding. "There is a symmetric and anti-symmetric relation which doesn't contain all elements of the form (a,a)". It will help if this explained. What I understand is on the left side ((S(A)∩T(A)), is intersection of symmetric and anti-symmetric relations, only (a,a), (b,b)... will be there. On the right side R(A), there will be reflexive relations like (a,a), (b,b)... So, why right side not subset of left side?

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions Since the right side has all the elements of such form but the left side doesn't necessarily contain all such elements (for example it can have only two elements.)

Comment: Is it not possible that R(A) contain only some elements. If (S(A)∩T(A)) can contain only some elements, why R(A) not so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129091/discussion-between-emad-and-splendid-digital-solutions).

Comment: I am sorry, it is mentioned clearly in the question that R(A) contains all reflexive relations.